# How can a pendrive filesystem become damaged?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, virus

Recently, I saw a directory containing strange filenames on a pendrive with a FAT32 filesystem.

```
ß×¸~ˇ¨>#>&;><ä, 2065.5.1 etc.
```

It's very strange, since I always remove the device safely. The pendrive capacity is 32 GB, and is just a half year old.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your system has been infected with virus. In folder options remove hide system files and enable show hidden files. Check if your pendrive contains a file named autorun.inf in its root. Use a good antivirus to check your system.

Comment: no virus found so far. Checkdisk also fixed those errors (deleted that directory...)

Comment: @JohnSmith - Let us put it this way.  The filename you listed is not allowed on a Windows machine.  So you need to format the drive in order to prevent your drive spreading a virus.

Comment: @JohnSmith Your antivirus may have missed the virus. Some viruses try to modify the partition table. There are viruses that edit the partition table and hide the entire content. Anyway  format the pendrive and update your anti virus. If you have another os installed on your machine install an antivirus in your second os and scan the other installation drive.